# Hibernate - AttributeConverter and custom SQL function

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to map EnumSet into a single value as integer via Hibernate.

I have implemented AttributeConverter:

```java
public class RolesToIntConverter implements AttributeConverter<Set<Roles>, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Set<Roles> attribute) {
        return Roles.encode(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Roles> convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
        return Roles.decode(dbData);
    }
}
```

As well as new SqlDialect:

```
public class LocalSqlDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {

    public LocalSqlDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("bitwise_and", new SQLFunctionTemplate(IntegerType.INSTANCE, "(?1 & ?2)"));
    }
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
public Collection<PersonsEntity> getAll(Roles roles) {
    Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT s FROM PersonsEntity AS s WHERE ( bitwise_and(s.roles,:roles) <> 0 )");
    q.setParameter("roles", EnumSet.of(roles));
    List<PersonsEntity> result = (List<PersonsEntity>) q.getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

This causes several issues:

- **ClassCastException**, because for some reason, it passes set to the `AttributeConverter` per each element
- I tried changing type from `Set<Roles>` to `Object` (at the converter), and then using *instanceof* I checked whether it is a single object or a set and parsed accordingly. After that I found out, that while calling `s.roles = :roles` worked fine, calling the registered `bitwise` function did not even call the `AttributeConverter`
- **ResultSet exception**, because after calling `bitwise` function and using as input `Set` with two values, it actually puts `?, ?` into the query instead of calling `AttributeParser`, which should merge it into a single number

**The question** is, what em I doing wrong? Or do you know a better solution to a problem: map `EnumSet` into a single database column, while being able to assign multiple roles to one entity.

**For example** I have value 1 for user, value 2 for manager, value 4 for admin, etc.. I want a particular person to be a user and a manager at the same time, which would mean value 3 (1 | 2) and then I want to find him when searching for user only (resp. manager only) via number 1 (resp. 2) - which suggests bitwise and.

Thank you in advance for any response!